# System stuttering caused by hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, lag

My system keeps freezing for about 1-2 second every time I try to do something. For example,  when I enter URL in browser, it freezes and starts working after few seconds. It is probably related to hard drive. I installed HD tune and when benchmark is in progress, causing constant disk use, everything works fine in background, there are no lags. What can be the reason of this issue?

My hardware is Acer Aspire 7740G-6969 running on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDD was changed, system was reinstalled and problem disappeared, so this mystery will remain unsolved.

Comment: Sounds like you actually solve the mystery.

Comment: @Ramhound: Still I don't know why turning on software, that heavily uses HDD, made system work fine, but yes, problem is solved:)

Comment: I appear to have this exact problem! I've got a new HD on order. Driving me crazy that I can't figure out what the actual problem is.

Comment: @DavidMasters84: I believe it was simply caused by HDD failure. I moved my problematic HDD to another computer and it doesn't work properly.

Comment: @LukLed OK thanks. I'm changing my HDD tomorrow hopefully.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, i don't think it sounds like a hardware issue. It sounds to me like a a program or service is using up more of the processor than it should.

Check whether there is something running which is using more of the CPU than it should by opening task manager (ctrl + alt + delete or right click the task bar and select 'Start task Manager') and navigating to the process tab. Sort by percentage of CPU usage by clicking on the CPU header. If you attempt to open your browser and notice that there is indeed a rogue process, i would hazard a guess and say it stems from some malware.

Comment: CPU usage is not jumping. It is clean system, no malware and as I said, running HD intensive software in background causes problem to disappear.

Comment: This being the case, the other possible causes of these symptoms are bad RAM or it could indicate a problem with the power supply. Try running memtest to rule out the ram as an issue (be sure to read the faq for instructions). As for the power, do the symptoms persist when the laptop is powered by its battery AND when it is powered via mains supply?

Comment: I have issues with power supply. My battery is old and it should be replaced. Can it be the reason?

Comment: It's beginning to sound like the likely culprit, yes. Unless someone else has a better solution, i would suggest replacing the battery and see whether this helps with your problem.

Comment: When battery is gone, this problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue before, caused by Hard Drive errors being written to the event log every second. Check your Event Viewer and the System subheading in case there are any errors.