# Hard stuttering in games, HDD failure or bottleneck?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, graphics-card

I recently bought a new Video card Nvidia 960gtx [the old card was 450gts]
and a new PSU Radix silver plus 750W.

Recently i notice some hard stuttering when i'm playing games like CS:GO and GTA5 [this one is more noticeable], unable to see where the problem was, i decided to reinstall windows 10 [build 10074] the problem persists so pondering the possibility of an OS bug, I decided to downgrade to Windows 7, atm i'm downloading GTA5, but meanwhile i was playing some CS:GO and the stuttering was noticeable with the download in the background.

The problem still, so i have suspicious of HDD failure.

SMART status shows:

> There are 381 bad sectors on the disk surface. The contents of these sectors were moved to the spare area. 1 errors occured during data transfer. This may indicate problem of the device or with data/power cables. It is recommended to examine and replace the cables if possible. Problems occurred between the communication of the disk and the host 28865 times.

### Build:

```
Operating System

Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit SP1

CPU

AMD Phenom II X6 1050T  36 °C
Thuban 45nm Technology

RAM

8,00GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 669MHz (9-9-9-24)

Motherboard

ASUSTeK Computer INC. M4A77T (AM3)  49 °C

Graphics

2047MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960 (Gigabyte)    32 °C

Storage

931GB Seagate ST31000528AS ATA Device (SATA) 35°C
698GB TOSHIBA STOR.E ALU 2S USB Device (USB (SATA))
```

Comment: You'd want to check the SMART status of your hard drive. This sounds like bad sectors to me. Related: http://superuser.com/questions/412997/system-stuttering-caused-by-hard-drive

Comment: "There are 381 bad sectors on the disk surface. The contents of these sectors were moved to the spare area.
1 errors occured during data transfer. This may indicate problem of the device or with data/power cables. It is recommended to examine and replace the cables if possible. 
Problems occurred between the communication of the disk and the host 28865 times."

I'm guessing this is bad?

Comment: On a scale of 1-10, where 10 is a dead drive, and 11 is your system exploding... its a 7-8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Your hard drive is failing and should be replaced as soon as possible.

- When your hard drive encounters **[bad sectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_sector)**, it moves the data located there to a special spare area in a process called *sector reallocation*. The presence of bad sectors on a hard drive indicates degrading disk media, which can eventually lead to **[drive failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive_failure)**.
- A hard drive undergoing reallocation will stop communicating with the computer as it repeatedly tries to read the data from the bad sectors. This is the likely cause of the *command timeouts* reported by your disk utility. Because Windows tends to block everything else while it retries failed I/O operations, this explains the repeated stuttering you're experiencing. These symptoms may also be caused by communication problems with your hard drive, so consider reseating the hard drive cables. **See: [Wikipedia article on S.M.A.R.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.)**
- You should back up your data and replace the hard drive as soon as possible. The best way to do this without needing to reinstall Windows is to perform a system image backup to an external hard drive and restore the backup to a new hard drive of the same or larger capacity. **See: [Back up your programs, system settings, and files](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/back-up-programs-system-settings-files#1TC=windows-7)**

Comment: What DragonLord did nt mention.  Is when a bad sector is detected or there is an I/O error Windows spends time trying to move the file or reading and writtng to the device instead of everything else.  This means everything else it normally does is put on hold, including not giving priority to the running process in the foreground.